# Why commands like "su", "passwd" in busybox cannot work properly?

Tags: linux, root, busybox

Background:

Debugging linux kernel 6.0 with qemu-system-x86_64. The start commandline is as follows:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel ./bzImage -initrd ./rootfs.img -serial stdio -append " console=ttyS0 nokaslr"`

The initrd `rootfs.img` is made by busybox-1.35.0 using the following commands:

```
$ make menuconfig   #choose [*] Build static binary (no shared libs)
$ make && make install
$ cd _install
$ ls
bin  linuxrc  sbin  usr

$ mkdir -p dev proc etc sys\kernel\debug sys\dev 
$ vim init
```

The `init` file is filled with:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "{==DBG==} INIT SCRIPT"
mkdir /tmp
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
mount -t tmpfs none /tmp

mdev -s
echo -e "{==DBG==} Boot took $(cut -d' ' -f1 /proc/uptime) seconds"

# normal user
setsid /bin/cttyhack setuidgid 1000 /bin/sh
```

```
$ find . | cpio -o --format=newc > ./rootfs.img
```

================================================================

The problem:

When I run`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel ./bzImage -initrd ./rootfs.img -serial stdio -append " console=ttyS0 nokaslr"` to start qemu. And enter the kernel successfully. But when I run "su" the problem occurs:

```
{==DBG==} INIT SCRIPT
{==DBG==} Boot took 2.63 seconds
/ $ su
su: must be suid to work properly
/ $
```

================================================================

What I tried:

I tried to google the problem. But only find to escalate the privilege.
Then I tried:

```
/ $ cd bin
/bin $ chmod u+s busybox 
/bin $ ls -l busybox 
-rwsr-xr-x    1 1000     1000       2408664 Oct 11 12:57 busybox
/bin $ su
su: must be suid to work properly
/bin $
```

Obviously the 'solution' failed.

================================================================

So what can I do to solve this problem? Or what causes this problem? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the init file showed, and the id command shows "uid=1000 gid=1000 groups=1000
"

Comment: What about the ```passwd``` command? It also shows the error ```must be suid to work properly```. I wonder if ```passwd``` cannot work in initrd mode as there has no logins at all?

Answer (score 1):

The suid bit that you added with `chmod u+s busybox` changes the current user to the owner of `/bin/busybox`, which as you can see is 1000.

So you want to change `/bin/busybox` to be owned by root:

```
$ chown root:root /bin/busybox
```

But you won't be able to do that from within your non-root shell; you must make this change in the root image `rootfs.img`.

It probably makes sense to have *all* files in the image owned by root. You don't need to change the ownership in the host file system, because you can do it while building the image:

```
$ find . | cpio -o --format=newc --owner=+0:+0 > ./rootfs.img
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above, but it didn't work. When I tried ```$ chown root:root /bin/busybox``` , it showed ```chown: unknown user/group root:root```.

Comment: I also tried ```$ chown 0:0 /bin/busybox```, and it showed ```chown: busybox: Operation not permitted```. Then I tried to modify the initrd image like you said ```$ find . | cpio -o --format=newc --owner=+0:+0 > ./rootfs.img```. When I tried ```su```, the problem is still there```su: must be suid to work properly```. Then I tried ```ls -hl busybox```, the result is as follows```-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0           2.3M Oct 11 12:57 busybox```.

Comment: By now, I kind of realize that maybe this question even doesn't make sense, as what the ```su``` command can do in this initrd mode.